# Growing a java array by creating a new one and making sure no memory leak occurs

Tags: java, arrays, memory-leaks, null, new-operator

Say I have the following `Stack` class (taken from Joshua Bloch's **Effective Java**):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stack {
    private Object[] elements;
    private int size = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;

    public Stack() {
        elements = new Object[DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    }

    public void push(Object e) {
        ensureCapacity();
        elements[size++] = e;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        if (size == 0)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        return elements[--size];
    }

    /**
     * Ensure space for at least one more element, roughly doubling the capacity
     * each time the array needs to grow.
     */
    private void ensureCapacity() {
        if (elements.length == size)
            elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 2 * size + 1);
    }
}
```

My question is about the `ensureCapacity` method and the `Arrays.copyOf` JDK method: how can we be positive that the old `elements` array object can be garbage collected since `copyOf` seems to be creating a new array object?

**In other words, if a new object is created each time `ensureCapacity` is called, where do the old objects go and is there no risk of a memory leak?**

Comment: Garbage collection to the rescue! You lose the reference to the previous object `elements` was pointing to.

Comment: "traditional" memory leaks in java are impossible(by the JLS anyway. A given JVM, may not perfectly follow the JLS). Java memory leaks are when you hold some reference to memory long after you need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "old objects" (the elements in the array) get copied into the new array in this line:

```
elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 2 * size + 1);
```

As for the old `elements` array, it'll eventually get garbage collected, because there are no more references pointing to it.